# Can I get rid of the RASAPI32.dll error?

Tags: windows-7

I am running Windows 7, when I boot up or shutdown my computer gives me an error that the `%WINDIR%\System32\RASAPI32.dll` file is missing or corrupt.  I have tried several ways to replace the file but can not gain access.  I am the administrator but the system will not allow me to remove, replace or delete the windows files.

P.S. The repair through Windows 7 did not fix it, nor did the restore to another time.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use SFC to repair it?

- Open the command prompt as admin (I type cmd in the startmenu then CTRL+Shift+Enter to launch as admin)
- Type `sfc /scannow`

You can also run `sfc /VERIFYFILE=c:\windows\system32\RASAPI32.dll`